# How to record a pressed key combination in the PyQT5 dialog window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, key-bindings

I open the dialog from the main window, where by clamping the keys, I fill the line with their names. The problem is that I can not understand where you need to do a cycle of checking all the keys on their state. Maybe there is another way to get the keys pressed? Or where you need to listen to the clamping so that the dialog box does not hang and the string is updated.

```
MainWindow:
    def showBindings(self, param):
        from dialogs import KeyBindingsDialog
        self.dialog = KeyBindingsDialog()
        self.dialog.show()

Dialog:
class KeyBindingsDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(KeyBindingsDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = KeyBindings()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use QKeySequenceEdit:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class KeySequenceEdit(QtWidgets.QKeySequenceEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super(KeySequenceEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)
        seq_string = self.keySequence().toString(QtGui.QKeySequence.NativeText)
        if seq_string:
            last_seq = seq_string.split(",")[-1].strip()
            le = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, "qt_keysequenceedit_lineedit")
            self.setKeySequence(QtGui.QKeySequence(last_seq))
            le.setText(last_seq)
            self.editingFinished.emit()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self._keysequenceedit = KeySequenceEdit(editingFinished=self.on_editingFinished)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("clear", clicked=self._keysequenceedit.clear)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hlay.addWidget(self._keysequenceedit)
        hlay.addWidget(button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_editingFinished(self):
        sequence = self._keysequenceedit.keySequence()
        seq_string = sequence.toString(QtGui.QKeySequence.NativeText)
        print("sequence: ", seq_string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The question is not how to open the window by key combination, but the fact that the user can assign a combination by pressing these keys, and so they need to be captured and entered into the field for display.

Comment: Oh, this is very similar to what you need, but how can I make an unlimited length of a combination and show them immediately when I click, for example, I press ctrl, it displays there and waits for further keys, and when I let go of all the clamped ones, I will record this combination, for example, as a string or a list into a variable?

Comment: How to limit the number of combinations of one?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need!

Comment: How can I make the window constantly listen to combinations, even when out of focus?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and you are right. QT methods do not suit me at all, I studied the api keyboard and there is the functionality I need, but read_hotkey captures the stream and the interface hangs. I need the capture to always wait while the dialog box is open, each pressing of the combination is shown in the Label overwriting the old one.

Comment: @eyllanesc Finally I 'am able to make comments.  You marked my post as duplicate and gave a link to this post. I love the way it works, but why are some keys like L Shift not working?

Comment: @SangonKim 1) When a person or a group of people closes your question you can notify with a comment using `@username` so if you could point that out to me before. 2)  I can execute Ctrl + L in my application (the shorcut L + Ctrl does not exist since the modifier is placed first), I have taken a picture of what I get: https://i.imgur.com/vynX7T3.png

Comment: Does 1) mean I can call you from my closed question?(Sorry I'm not that fluent with english) And I think there was a confusion, I meant left shift key not L + shift.

Comment: @SangonKim 1) Make a comment in the comments section similar to this space below your question. 2) There is no "L + Shift" key, there is the combination of the L key + the Shitf key, but as I pointed out by convention it is to put the modifier first, in this case the modifier is the shift, so it is shown "Shitf + L", and not "L + shitf"

Comment: I understood 1). And as I mentioned I'm not talking about L+Shift. I'm talking about the shift key on the left side of the keyboard. For example I', curious why it does not show ```Shift``` when it can show ```Shift+L```

Comment: @SangonKim Okay, I understand you. By convention a shortcut must have at least one key that is not a modifier. In your case the LShitf is not a shorcut so it is not shown

Comment: Ah so ````shift``` is not a shortcut so it's not shown. But why is ```Tab```key and ```PrtSc``` key and  right```Alt```key and right ```Ctrl```key not working? Well I can think that ```PrtSc``` and ```Tab``` are not enlisted in PyQt, but why are the ````Alt``` and ```Ctrl``` keys on the other side of the keyboard doesn't work like the ones on the left side?

Comment: @SangonKim `Ctrl + Tab` itself is a shortcut, PrtSc is not a shorcut, is a special key, that key is not handled by any GUI only the OS.

Comment: @eyllanesc How can I change the text shown when QKeySequenceEdit is empty?